# Getting DataIntegrityViolationException when integrated new mongo ATLAS credentials in java application

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE. So there was mongo upgraded in org, we migrated old mongo to new mongo atlas (6.0), previously it was 3.6.something.
Now after giving new creds to application and while trying to run it is giving below expcetion:

`Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Cannot create index for 'StudentId' in collection 'Info' with keys 'Document{{Id=1}}' and options 'Document{{name=Id, unique=true}}'.; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 85: 'Index already exists with a different name: Id_1' on server xyz.abc. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Index already exists with a different name: Id_1", "code" : 85, "codeName" : "IndexOptionsConflict", "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 312323, "i" : 1 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "asdsadsadasad/tJ8=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "2342424" } } }, "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 42344324, "i" : 1 } } }`

Talking about more mongo depencies, So i have below mongo dependency in pom :

spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb
querydsl-mongodb